# icheck jQuery Plugin Show/Hide DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I work with icheck plugin and show/hide `div` when I click/checked check box.

HTML:

```
<input tabindex="5" type="checkbox" id="minimal-checkbox-1" checked>checked
<div class="max_tickets">
    <input type="text" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][0][maxtickets]" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal',
    increaseArea: '20%'
});

$('input').on('ifChanged', function () {
    $(this).parent().next('.max_tickets').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

CSS:

```
max_tickets {display:none;}
```

Now for dynamic checkbox I need to add `checked` in icheck input and show `div` in default. 
But In default I have `display:none;` and `div` not show.

How do Fix This problem and display `max_tickets` `div` in defualt ?

**DEMO HERE** : http://jsfiddle.net/224bR/

Comment: I think issue is `this.checkbox` value is `false` at the first time.
Use `$(this).parent().next('.max_tickets').toggle(t);`

Answer (score 0):

Removing the CSS for `.max_tickets` will leave it displayed by default

```
.max_tickets {display:none;}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/224bR/2/)